# can't access an asmx file out of folder

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have javascript in my aspx file in a folder, and i want to access a file name webservice.asmx out of folder, but i can't

this is code for url in javascript

```
url: "~/WebService.asmx/GetData"
```

i already tried to change ~ to .. but still can't work.

this is the link of the pictures:

-http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/547/519h.png/

-http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/546/g6hb.png/

what is the best solution to my problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tilde won't resolve in your javascript files, they aren't run through the ASP.Net runtime. What you need to do is resolve the tilde in your ASP.Net page, and then pass that value to a javascript variable or function.

Put this in your aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urlPrefix = '<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~")';
</script>
```

Now `urlPrefix` will contain your application root path.

Of course, this creates a global variable which is typically a bad idea, I would typically pass this value to an initializer for some object instead.